# Update OpenGL on Intel Integrated Graphics?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, intel-graphics, opengl

I'm a little confused on how to update opengl for Intel integrated graphics. I have an old laptop with an i3 M330 processor in it and I'm attempting to run a program that requires at least openGL 3.2. It states that I currently have openGL 2.1 and that 3.2 is the minimum version required, but I have no idea how to update it since it's not a dedicated video card with its own drivers.

How would I update opengl to at least 3.2 on intel integrated graphics?

Comment: According to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units#Gen5 it only supports OpenGL up to 2.1. To update OpenGL you need to update drivers for Intel HD Graphics from Device Manager.

Comment: Support depends on hardware as well as drivers. If you do not have capable hardware (and the latest drivers don't help) then you will have to get newer hardware.